# remote_file capistrano 3 method

Tags: capistrano, capistrano3

In capistrano 3 docs (http://capistranorb.com/documentation/advanced-features/remote-file/) an example is provided to show how this task (remote_file) works

```
namespace :deploy do
    namespace :check do
        task :linked_files => 'config/newrelic.yml'
    end
end

remote_file 'config/newrelic.yml' => '/tmp/newrelic.yml', roles: :app

file '/tmp/newrelic.yml' do |t|
    sh "curl -o #{t.name} https://rpm.newrelic.com/accounts/xx/newrelic.yml"
end
```

They tell it allows a presence of remote file to be set as a prerequisite. 
Hovewer I still can't get how it works as remote_file is called outside task code. What does it actually do? Can someone explain?

What happens if config/newrelic.yml is absent and how is remote_file call connected with 
:linked_files task?

Answer (score 1):

Calling `remote_file` only *defines* a task named 'config/newrelic.yml'. It does not execute that task. The line

```
remote_file 'config/newrelic.yml' => '/tmp/newrelic.yml', roles: :app
```

is saying "create a task named 'config/newrelic.yml' that has a prerequisite task named '/tmp/newrelic.yml'". The `file '/tmp/newrelic.yml'` part defines this prerequisite task. Finally, `task :linked_files => 'config/newrelic.yml'` is specifying a prerequisite task named 'config/newrelic.yml' to be executed, which we defined using the `remote_file` method.

Comment: It seems clear except why  task name is given like /tmp/newrelic.yml and looks like file path? Does content of given file contain task code?

Comment: You'll want to read up on the Rake file tasks, which is what remote_file uses. The file tasks are special in that they expect to be named with a path to a file to work. Here is a nice blog post explaining it http://madewithenvy.com/ecosystem/articles/2013/rake-file-tasks/